# upload file after selecting file

Tags: jquery

i have this form which is appended onclick of a div

```
$('#div').click(function(){
   $('#div').load('form.php');
});
```

here is the form appended

```
    <form id="addpic" name="addpic" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="docupload.php">
      <input type="file" name="mfoni" id="upper1" style="height:10px; width:100px; cursor:hand;" />
      <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="user" />
   </form>
```

now i want to submit the form without refreshing the page or redirecting with the code below

```
$("input#upper1").live('change', function(){
       alert("gone");
       // works up to this point
       $("form#addpic").ajaxForm({
         target: '#loading'
      }).submit();
    })
```

this works up to the alert('gone') point and it stops
please healp me out

Comment: **.live** function is deprecated

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: is the syntax for delegate() the same as live()

Comment: @user2922439: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing below external JS file reference

http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js

The other thing is you need to use `.on()` rather than using `.live()`. Since `live()` method has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7.

You no need to use `ajaxForm()` and `.submit()`. Just use `ajaxSubmit()`.

### JS Code:

```
$("input#upper1").on('change', function(){
    alert("gone");
    $("form#addpic").ajaxSubmit({
        type: "post",
        success: function() {
            alert("Processed");
        },
        complete: function() {
            alert("File upload is completed");
        }
    });
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/yaASE/)**